# Fast way to check if String contains a word from a dictionary file?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Say I have a file with words:

- Apple
- Bacon
- Phone
- And so on, there are about 2000 words.

I then have a string:

```
I was eating some Apple-bacon when the phoNe rang.
```

I'm trying to find a fast way to result in:

```
I was eating some *****-***** when the ***** rang.
```

I'm basically trying to censor a chat box. I'm just wondering if there is a better way than iterating through a vector. I'm only using the standard library so a boost hashmap is not a possibility.

I'm using C++ 98.

Comment: C++11 provides `unordered_map`. And it is `Standard Library` not `STL`.

Comment: Word censors doesn't work very well in chat. You will soon se lots of Bac0n and Ph0nes.

Comment: I think that censorship and refusing to use boost are just immoral. Also, both decisions usually cause more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: since no one mentione it, the problem with this type of cencorship is people who multicl*** as an ******in (assassin).

Comment: also, many C++98 compilers have a tr1::hashtable (or maybe unordered_map, not sure which)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm just wondering if there is a better way than iterating through a vector.

Use either [`binary_search`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/binary_search.html) on a sorted vector or `std::set` for guaranteed O(lg *n*) lookup time. lg(2000) = 7.6, a 263-fold speed increase in theory, disregarding any constant factors.

(Though this is really a better fit for regular expressions.)

Answer (score 2):

If the string to be censored is very long you may try to optimize by iterating the string only once.
Construct a tree with the letters from the list of words you are searching from and write a function that use this map to find words. The design is complicated but for long strings and many words to search will be probably fastest.

Example:

words: Ape, Ace, Apa, By,

Tree

```
       A     B
    /  |     |
    p  c     y
   /|  |
  e a  e
```

search:

1) iterate trough every char in string  for top level chars (A or B)
2) if found check if next letter is child of first.

note that iterating chars in string is done anyway for each `strchr` and is fast because of the [branch prediction](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~downeyt/cop3402/prediction.html) and should be a primitive implementation of regexp.

Comment: I find it simplifies the algorithm to have all 26+ word roots be children of a single root.

Comment: This is known as a trie search

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks stefaanv. I was remembering only the idea not the name. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives to speed up the search.
One of the simpler approaches if you already have a vector of words, is to [sort](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html) the vector and to do a [binary_search](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/binary_search.html)

Answer (score 1):

Trie search is probably the best way. Build a tree of all words in the dictionary and compare input from top. When sees non alphabet letter, reset and start from the top of the tree again

Answer (score 0):

The first attempt would be to tokenize the phrase and look up every word in a map or a [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/).

However, if you have a server which has to process a lot of messages, you could think about implementing it a bit more clever. Walk through the string, character by character and search inside some better datastructure like those:

- suffix tree of all the words, or
- hashvalues of all the words

Then replace the characters in place with a *.

Suffix tree should be really fast, but wastes a lot of memory. Hashvalues might be faster than a set implementation, but you have to come up with a clever algorithm.